# Lodash - How to get multiple results

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using lodash. I like it.

I have a users array which looks like this:

```
var users = [{
    'user': 'barney',
    'age': 36,
    'active': true
}, {
    'user': 'fred',
    'age': 40,
    'active': false
}, {
    'user': 'pebbles',
    'age': 1,
    'active': true
}];
```

Here's how I'm finding the first user and plucking the `user` property:

```
_.result(_.find(users, 'active', false), 'user');
// 'fred'
```

However, I wanted to pluck the `user` and the `age` values. How can I write this?

Comment: `_.find(users, 'active', false)` will return you an object, You can use it like `var obj = _.find(users, 'active', false); ` and then get `obj.user` and `obj.age`

Comment: What answer do you expect? A new object with user name and age ?

Comment: Yes, vjdhama new object I want

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vs6tpd5/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to select the `user` and `age` columns from a single result you can use the [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function like this:

```
_.pick(_.find(users, 'active'), ['user', 'age']);
// 'barney', 36
```

If you want to filter and *project* then you can use [where()](https://lodash.com/docs#where) and [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map):

```
_.map(_.where(users, 'active'), _.partialRight(_.pick, ['user', 'age']));
// [{ name: 'barney', age: 36 }, { user: 'pebbles', age: 1 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Will Smith

Answer (score 1):

If you want the object user in the array and not the attribute 'user', you can get it from _.find.

```
_.find(users, 'active', false);
// {'user': 'fred', 'age': 40, 'active': false}
```